# Getting FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION on my nexus, but not on the emulator

Tags: java, android

I am testing the Facebook SDK sample Scrumptious, that simply logs you in to Facebook. When I run the app on my Galaxy Nexus, I get a `FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION`, from the app, but I don't get that error on my emulator.  It's pretty confusing.

Any ideas?

EDIT
Logcat:

```
01-30 19:50:14.756: D/dalvikvm(3976): Late-enabling CheckJNI
01-30 19:50:14.842: I/dalvikvm(3976): Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 8...
01-30 19:50:18.639: D/dalvikvm(3976): GC_CONCURRENT freed 266K, 3% free 10961K/11271K, paused 20ms+6ms, total 60ms
01-30 19:50:18.639: D/dalvikvm(3976): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 13ms
01-30 19:50:18.670: D/dalvikvm(3976): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 58K, 4% free 11117K/11527K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
01-30 19:50:18.670: I/dalvikvm-heap(3976): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.496MB for 640016-byte allocation
01-30 19:50:18.685: D/dalvikvm(3976): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 4% free 11741K/12167K, paused 4ms+1ms, total 15ms
01-30 19:50:18.709: D/dalvikvm(3976): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 184K, 5% free 11714K/12231K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
01-30 19:50:18.725: D/dalvikvm(3976): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 26K, 4% free 11815K/12231K, paused 11ms, total 11ms
01-30 19:50:18.764: D/dalvikvm(3976): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 31K, 3% free 12036K/12359K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
01-30 19:50:18.779: D/dalvikvm(3976): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 102K, 4% free 12184K/12615K, paused 11ms, total 11ms
01-30 19:50:20.162: D/dalvikvm(3976): GC_CONCURRENT freed 169K, 3% free 12431K/12743K, paused 13ms+2ms, total 31ms
01-30 19:50:20.350: E/JavaBinder(3976): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
01-30 19:50:42.685: E/JavaBinder(3976): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
01-30 19:50:52.428: E/JavaBinder(3976): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
01-30 19:50:55.600: E/JavaBinder(3976): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
01-30 19:51:00.029: E/JavaBinder(3976): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
01-30 19:55:07.748: D/dalvikvm(4659): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 90K, 2% free 11076K/11271K, paused 17ms, total 18ms
01-30 19:55:07.756: I/dalvikvm-heap(4659): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.457MB for 640016-byte allocation
01-30 19:55:07.771: D/dalvikvm(4659): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2K, 2% free 11699K/11911K, paused 12ms+1ms, total 22ms
01-30 19:55:07.826: D/dalvikvm(4659): GC_CONCURRENT freed 239K, 3% free 11955K/12295K, paused 11ms+2ms, total 23ms
01-30 19:55:07.826: D/dalvikvm(4659): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 4ms
01-30 19:55:07.873: D/dalvikvm(4659): GC_CONCURRENT freed 112K, 3% free 12293K/12551K, paused 12ms+2ms, total 25ms
01-30 19:55:09.560: E/JavaBinder(4659): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
01-30 19:55:11.021: D/dalvikvm(4659): GC_CONCURRENT freed 300K, 3% free 12431K/12807K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 17ms
01-30 19:55:21.857: E/JavaBinder(4659): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
01-30 19:55:25.685: E/JavaBinder(4659): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
```

Comment: is the nexus online? if so wifi or 3g/4g? Also do you have droidwall or any other type of firewall that could be preventing the app from getting to the internet?

Comment: Can you post log cat output??

Comment: I debugged through the code, and I'm seeing that in the LoginButton code, fetchUserInfo() line 554, SessionTracker is never returning an open session.  Could this be related?

Comment: I also found out that when I run the code in the emulator SessionTracker returns a session but not on my phone.  I don't have an y security apps on my phone, and I've tried killing all other apps, including Facebook, using a advanced task manager.